# How to refer to an fxml file from css stylesheet in separate packages

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a package with my main class `ClientMain` and css styleSheet in it.

In another package I have the fxml files and objects I want to refer to.
If i now type, for example,

```
.Button{-fx-fill:pink;}
```

The css file doesn't seem to `reach` the fxml object I am referring to.

How do I refer to an fxml file from css stylesheet in separate packages?

Comment: Create a [mcve] and show your problem.

Comment: If the style sheet is applied to the scene or parent node, the rules defined in it will be applied to all the nodes in the scene (or contained in the parent node). If it's not working, you have something else wrong - this has nothing to do with packages. Note that `.Button` is not the correct selector for a button (unless you are explicitly adding that class); either `.button` or `Button` should work.